# discord.py command not working when defining in separate file

Tags: python, discord.py

I've started creating a very basic bot using discord.py. I want to define my commands in a separate .py file, but when I'm doing so the command isn't working.

main.py

```
import BotCommands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
client.load_extension("BotCommands")
```

BotCommands.py

```
from discord.ext import commands


@commands.command()
async def hello(message, arg):
    print("inside hello")
    await message.send('Hello {0}.'.format(arg))


def setup(bot):
    print("Inside Setup")
    bot.add_command(hello)
```

I'm not getting any errors. 'Inside Setup' is being printed but 'inside hello' is not when run `!hello test` command

Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm new to stack overflow and discord.py so, please let me know if I should do something differently the next time.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I would watch out with discord.py in general. Development has stopped for a few months (august 2021) now, and the discord API tends to change rather quickly. For example, a huge change of rules will come into play in April 2022 that will probably break discord.py entirely. Therefore, even if you get your bot to work, it could break to an unfixable level quite quickly. Source: https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/4a2f62751b9600a31a0d3c78100287f1

Comment: Then more of a stackoverflow suggestion: Add your TraceBack/error that you receive when running your code.

Comment: @lcdumort Thank you for the news but since this is more like a hobby thing for me and I am not building a large-scale bot I'm fine if it stops working in the future. And for the StackOverflow suggestion, I had that in mind but I'm not getting any errors the program control is going inside the setup function but I think the issue is in ```bot.add_command(hello)``` line

Comment: @lcdumort also if you could suggest any alternative to discord.py it would really nice

Comment: two come to mind: pycord and hikari. I would suggest the former, as this is a clone from discord.py and will therefore be familiar if you have any experience with discord.py

Comment: @lcdumort will look into pycord, thanks once again!